# Close not responding program instantly

Tags: windows

When a program is not responding and I hit close I want it to close instantly. I don't want to have to confirm or wait. Is there any option I can set in the registry of some other way to do this?

Comment: Try closing from Task Manager.   Programs closed forcefully show up in Reliability History. So you might wish to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the window close button a message is sent to the application. If the application takes no specific action the application will be closed. But if the application handles the message it can do anything the developer chooses, including ignore it completely. Text editors often ask if any modified files should be saved before closing the program. In some cases the application will offer options to configure that action that will be taken. But in any case you are limited to what the developer chooses to provide.

If the application is busy doing other things it may not be able to process the close message. This is most common with single threaded applications but can happen with others as well. This situation may be temporary or it may be permanent. In such cases you may need to use other methods to close the application, such as Task Manager.